# creating nested rails route without parent id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, url-rewriting, routes, nested-routes

I have 2 tables:
campus (has_one) and notification (belongs_to)

I want to setup my routes so the index url uses the following format:
/campusname/notifications

=> campusname is an unique value

With the nested routes my url always has an id.
/campus/:campu_id/notifications

Currently my routes.rb looks like this:

```
  shallow do
    resources :campus do
      resources :notifications
    end
  end
```

How can I get rid of that id and use the campusname instead?

And more importantly how do I edit my controller to show the right notifications for every campus? Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your route is working correctly, you just want to make it more user friendly. One option would be to use the [FriendlyId gem](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)

FriendlyId allows you to allows you to use human friendly strings instead of ids, for example:

```
http://example.com/states/washington
```

instead of:

```
http://example.com/states/4323454
```

Comment: please add little more description for your answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. I first have to get my controller to work properly.